# Cannot Boot after Upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, systemd

About 20 minutes ago, I performed a standard upgrade ("apt-get upgrade"). Upon reboot, I was dropped to an emergency shell, and cannot boot normally. Here is the information from /var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Start-Date: 2018-02-05  23:47:41
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libsystemd0:i386 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), grub-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), libxatracker2:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4), grub2-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), udev:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4), grub-pc:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libgbm1:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), systemd-sysv:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4), libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), grub-rescue-pc:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16), systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21, 229-4ubuntu21.1), libmbim-proxy:amd64 (1.12.2-2ubuntu1, 1.14.0-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4), libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.12.2-2ubuntu1, 1.14.0-1ubuntu0.16.04.1), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4)
End-Date: 2018-02-05  23:49:30
```

I believe the mostly likely package at fault would be systemd, since it did (sort of) boot, but I'm quite unsure. This occured on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

**Update:** Choosing the same kernel but with Upstart next to it in grub succeeded in booting. I am getting systemd-login errors, however. This made the system usable, at least for me, though a lot of Ubuntu users would have been stuck. This should be a priority.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the versions of Ubuntu are you upgrading from/to.

Comment: I updated the question. It was Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: @richbl - apt-get upgrade isn't  version upgrade.

Comment: @SarahC.Corriher -- `apt-get upgrade` only does half the job of updating a system. try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to complete updating your system.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. Still can't boot unless I choose the Upstart option.

Comment: There are messages that get logged before emergency mode is invoked that _tell one what the problem is_.  You haven't shown them to us, and we cannot see your machine.

Answer (score 0):

To my very humble knowledge, it looks as if I'm affected by the same problem. Did an automatic update this afternoon and afterwards I got the grub shell screen, where I have no clue what to do.

I've got a fully updated (until that fateful update today) Ubuntu 16.04 running on a HP 350 G2 (i7-5500U@2.4 GHz, 8 GB DDR3L SDRAM@1600 MHz, AMD Radeon R5 M240). Thank you for any help and tips on what to do! :)

edit: Solved the issue via a boot repair tool and used it according to this guide: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: ah, sorry, I've realised I should have posted this as a comment. I'm very new at this, please excuse me.

Comment: I believe that you can delete your own answer, if you feel that you've placed this in the wrong area - if you remain on this site for note terribly long, you will have enough reputation points to make comments.

Comment: Thank you Charles Green! I just saw myself that I can't comment on the previous post, so I will let my unhelpful answer stay in order to support the claim by venerable Sarah C. Corriher.

Comment: @Schwrzwolf I was able to get a sort-of boot by choosing a kernel with the word Upstart next to it from GRUB. Can you do that? It's not idyllic, but it made my system functional.

Comment: Thank you Sarah C. Corriher! I was unable to choose a kernel with the guides I found online - they're probably too complicated for me :D

Anyhow, I managed to get my grub2 repaired thanks to a boot repair tool and this guide: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ I just did the general repair and now ubuntu starts just as usual and it is still booting after applying updates via the update manager. Seems like everything is fixed now \o/