# Ubuntu 16.04 had been working well for over a year. After a standard update, re-boot freezes on purple screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, grubrescue

Ubuntu 16.04 had been working well for over a year. Then, after a standard software update, as it was very slow I shut down and tried to re-boot.

I was led first to the blank purple screen. Eventually I got the menu to select recovery linux versions. I tried Linux 4.15.0-39-generic and that tried to boot, getting to a black and white screen ending with 
---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)

I tried getting to the Grub prompt but had no success trying to boot manually, using the sugggestions in thread [After update in Ubuntu 16.04 I ended up in GNU GRUB and appear to be stuck there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003440/after-update-in-ubuntu-16-04-i-ended-up-in-gnu-grub-and-appear-to-be-stuck-there)

Comment: try booting into an older kernel version, and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I got the right verion of the vmlinuz file in the boot directory. Then I tried

grub> set root=(hd0,2)
grub> linux (hd0,2)/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd (hd0,2)/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-89-generic
grub> boot

where instead of the above values I used the full path to my vlinuz and initrd files. This, also ansuring to point to sda2, finaly got back to a good boot with all files intact etc